# Select data having count > 1 in any interval of 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I am using MySql. Suppose that I have a table with logs, like this:

```
+---------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id |      timestamp      |   event    |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
|       1 | 2016-12-11 01:00:00 | some event |
|       2 | 2016-12-11 01:00:00 | some event |
|       2 | 2016-12-11 03:00:00 | some event |
|       3 | 2016-12-11 01:59:00 | some event |
|       3 | 2016-12-11 02:00:00 | some event |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

I would like to find out the occasions when the same user had more than 1 log in any interval of 1 hour.

So, I would like the query to return me the following data:

```
+---------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id |      timestamp      |   event    |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
|       3 | 2016-12-11 01:59:00 | some event |
|       3 | 2016-12-11 02:00:00 | some event |
+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Whats wrong with `between` operator? You can do `timestamp between t1 and t2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  *
from    t
where   exists
        (
            select      null                
            from        t as t2                
            where       t2.user_id   =  t.user_id
                    and t2.timestamp <> t.timestamp
                    and t2.timestamp between t.timestamp - interval 1 hour
                                     and     t.timestamp + interval 1 hour

        )
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select l.*
from logs l
where exists (select 1
              from logs l2
              where l2.user_id = l.user_id and
                    l2.timestamp = l.timestamp and
                    l2.timestamp between date_sub(l.timestamp, interval 1 hour) and
                                         date_add(l.timestamp, interval 1 hour)
            );
```

Note:  To get both rows, you need to check one hour before and one hour after.

Comment: This returns all rows. You should eliminate self reference.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . That's funny.  When I first started typing out the solution I was going to use two `exists` (one for before and one for after).  The `between` was a last minute change to reduce typing.